# PHP: Conditional charset replace in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, replace, character-encoding

I have a site scraped into $html variable.

now i want to replace some chars with this expression

```
$string1 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9äöü!&_=\+-]/i', ' ', $string);
```

The Problem is there are special characters caused by different charsets.

I have a variable $charset in which the charset string of the page is saved.
i.e. $charset="utf-8" or iso-8859-1
in utf-8 it's the german letter ü i want to replace in iso-8859-1 it's Ã¼

Is there a possibility to tell the replace function according to the charset of the page
without making separate Regular Expressions for each possible charset?

Comment: if you know the charsets you can use http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can try adding

```
utf8_encode($string);
```

RIGHT BEFORE preg_replace. I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but it might.

For more information, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php.